# Tapgesture and touch events not working which created by custom uiview with xib?

Tags: ios, view, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to show some content with custom `UIView` as pop up, so far I done it good, I want to release the pop up by touching Pop up view, I cannot get it as success, I am new to swift language, can you please help me with this, All code only copied from Google only,

Code For Custom `UIView`

```
import UIKit

class PopUpView: UIView {
    var view = UIView()
    var _myTap: UITapGestureRecognizer?
    // this name has to match your class file and your xib file
    @IBOutlet weak var lblContent: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    func _myHandleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .Ended {
            print("_myHandleTap(sender.state == .Ended)")
            sender.view!.backgroundColor
                = UIColor(red: CGFloat(drand48()), green: CGFloat(drand48()), blue: CGFloat(drand48()), alpha: 1.0);
            self .hideInView()
        }
    }
    func setup() {
        // setup the view from .xib
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view .userInteractionEnabled = true
        self .userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        _myTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self
            , action: #selector(_myHandleTap(_:)))
        _myTap!.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(_myTap!)

    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        // grabs the appropriate bundle
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
    func showInView(currentView:UIView,content:String) {
        view.frame = currentView.bounds
        currentView .userInteractionEnabled = true
        lblContent.text = content
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(view)
        view.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    func hideInView() {
        view.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.view.alpha = 0
            self.view .removeFromSuperview()
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self .hideInView()
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        return true

    }
}
```

Accessing it from my `UIViewController`

```
@IBAction func doForgotAction(sender: AnyObject) {
//        warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will significantly reduce the quality of type information available.
        let  custom = PopUpView()
        custom .showInView(self .view, content: "welcome")

    }
```

Comment: is your function _myHandleTap is called?

Comment: that is not calling i have checked with break point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got my answer,
The main problem is events are not received, whether its created by xib or programmatically

I have changed all code to below

```
import UIKit

class PopUpView: UIView {
    var view = UIView()
    // this name has to match your class file and your xib file
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblContent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var _myTap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    @IBAction func tapGestureAction(sender: AnyObject) {
         self .hideInView()
    }
    func setup() {
        // setup the view from .xib
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        self .userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
        // grabs the appropriate bundle
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "PopUpView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
    }
    func showInView(currentView:UIView,content:String) {
        self.frame = currentView.bounds
        self .layoutIfNeeded()
        lblContent.text = content
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.addSubview(self)
        self.alpha = 0
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.alpha = 1
            }, completion: nil)

    }
    func hideInView() {
        self.alpha = 1
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.alpha = 0
            self .removeFromSuperview()
            }, completion: nil)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self .hideInView()
    }
    func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        return true

    }
}
```

All are working good after changing this follow line

```
func setup() {
        // setup the view from .xib
        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        self .userInteractionEnabled = true
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
```

}

Now i can get tapgesture and touchevents.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the outlet action method in your Custom View Class and and the touch and tap gesture in this class. Now in order to receive the effect of these touches and taps, you have to create a delegate and add the delegate method to your view controller in order to receive the touches and taps.